# how can i connect my form to ajax and post through it

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

my html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% block content %}*
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Create a Recipe</title>
  <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
    <br>
    <label for="T">Title: </label>
    <input type="text" name="T" value="">
    <br>
    <label for="Ingr">Ingredients: </label>
    <select class="" name="Ingr">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="Tag">Tags: </label>
    <select class="" name="Tag">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="Time">Time: </label>
    <input type="text" name="Time" value="">
    <br>
    <label for="P">Price: </label>
    <input type="text" name="P" value="">
    <br>
  </form>
</head>
<body class="">
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

    var data = {
    title: 'title',
    tags: [],
    ingredients: [],
    time_minutes: 25,
    price: 10.5
};
var headers = {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' };  // Inject our token into the javascript using a template tag
  $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: data,
       headers: headers,  // Set the headers in the request
       url: '/api/recipe/recipes/',
       success: function(res){
               console.log(res)
       },
   });


</script>
{%endblock%}
```

error:
[image]

I want to know how to access my form in ajax I have the var data and it's working it posts but I want the data to be taken from the form in the body I mean I want the user to put his own data from the form I have been struggling to do it Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the values entered like this:

```
var data = {
    title: $('[name="T"]').val(),
    tags: $('[name="Tag"]').val(),
    ingredients: $('[name="Ingr"]').val(),
    time_minutes: $('[name="Time"]').val(),
    price: $('[name="P"]').val()
};
```

And you'd execute your code when the form is submitted:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() { /* your code here */ });
```

Comment: hello thank you so much but I am really a beginner can u give me an example about what should I write in /* your code here */ and is this function written inside function(res)?

Comment: By "your code" I mean everything you have inside the second <script>, having changed the data variable like I showed

Comment: so this function wraps up everything in the second script , right?

Comment: what does the action in the form have to be?

Comment: It doesn't matter, since you're sending the data with jquery to another endpoint. The action would be used if you didn't have js code, and form data would be sent to the endpoint specified in it

Comment: i am getting an error i will add it above